# In ES6 is it correct to think of ExecutionContexts as the stack frames of the JavaScript virtual machine?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 is it correct to think of `ExecutionContexts` as the stack frames of the JavaScript virtual machine?

Reference: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-1-lexical-environments-common-theory/#activation-record-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-execution-contexts):

> A stack is used to track execution contexts. The running execution
>   context is always the top element of this stack. A new execution
>   context is created whenever control is transferred from the executable
>   code associated with the currently running execution context to
>   executable code that is not associated with that execution context.
>   The newly created execution context is pushed onto the stack and
>   becomes the running execution context.