# Execution context for object literals and object literal methods

Tags: javascript, this

```
var objLiteral = {
    name: 'Kumar'
    myNameIs: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};
objLiteral.name = 'Arvind';
objLiteral.myNameIs(); // returns Arvind
```

Can someone explain how the creation phase and execution phase run through this code? I understand how this works for let, const, functions (global execution context, function execution context) but not for object literals.

Here is my take so far:

- Creation phase:

  1. the `objLiteral` object `{}` is placed somewhere in memory and is 'live and accessible' and not garbage collected until the end of the program.
  2. a memory location is created for the property `name` with a pointer returned back to the object so that it can be found during execution.
  3. a memory location is created for the method `myNameIs` with a pointer returned back to the object so that it can be found during execution.
- Execution phase:

  1. `objLiteral.name` is set to the value `'Arvind'`, by tracing the memory locations previously stored.
  2. then `objLiteral.myNameIs()` is invoked and using the memory location of the object and the pointer to the method/`myNameIs` a 'function execution context' is created. The value of `this` is taken from the object the method is called on. Therefore `this==objLiteral`
  3. Since `this` is the same as `objLiteral` the memory trace to the location of the value is the same as `objLiteral.name` and it returns `'Arvind'`

When is the variable `objLiteral` assigned a value i.e. given a reference to the object? During the creation phase or execution phase?

Comment: Why do you care? It is likely implementation specific

Comment: @ruan I don't see how this was a duplicate

Comment: "*I'm unable to see the creation or execution phase separately so I cannot answer my main question. Does anyone have a tool that they know of whereby I can actually see the two stages running?*" - no. Those two stages are only conceptual, not necessarily implemented separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is my take so far. Creation phase: the `objLiteral` object `{}` is placed somewhere in memory and is 'live and accessible' and not garbage collected until the end of the program.

No, absolutely not. An execution context, and the separation between creation phase and execution phase, has nothing to do with object (literal) creation. It is solely about code execution, whether that is in the global script scope or in a function call. [An execution context basically is a stack frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750387/1048572).

Objects from object literals are allocated, created and mutated during the execution phase, never during the creation phase<sup>1</sup>.

So what happens in your example is:

1. *creation phase* of the global context:

   - the variable `objLiteral` is allocated and initialised with `undefined`
2. *execution phase* of the global script:

   1. an object is created, a string `Kumar` is created and placed in its `.name` property, a function (with a closure over the current scope) is created and placed in its `.myNameIs` property, the object is assigned to the `objLiteral` variable
   2. the object in the variable `objLiteral` is looked up, a string `Arvind` is created assigned to the object's `.name` property
   3. the object in the variable `objLiteral` is looked up, its `.myNameIs` property is looked up, and is invoked as a method. This creates a new execution context:

      1. *creation phase* of function call:

         - a new scope is created
         - the `this` value is set to the method call receiver, i.e. the object
         - no variable or parameter declarations need to be set up in your example
      2. *execution phase* of the function call:

         1. the object in `this` is looked up and its `.name` property is accessed
         2. that value is `return`ed, ending the function execution

      The execution context of the function ends, its local scope is no longer referenced and can be garbage-collected, the execution of the global script resumes with the returned string value.

Garbage collection has nothing to do with this either. Objects are garbage-collected as soon as they are no longer referenced from anything (variables or properties), variables (and scopes) are garbage-collected as soon as they are no longer referenced from anything (live stack frames or closures).

<sub>1: I wrote "from object literals" specifically, as some function objects are created during the creation phase from `function` declarations</sub>

Comment: Beautiful. I can sleep easy now. I have been wrestling with issue for many nights. Thanks so much this.

Comment: I may have some follow up questions.

Comment: @KumarDesai Just ask them :-) If this has solved your question, please consider [upvoting and/or accepting the answer](/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I had a question about 'arrow function methods' but have since figured out that in an object literal an arrow function's 'this' is taken from the execution context of the previous item on the stack. In the above example this is the window object. All good for now.

Comment: @KumarDesai No, it's not taken from the previous execution context on the stack, which would depend on when and where the function is called. It's taken from the outer scope at the moment when the arrow function is created.